# operator overloading with templates

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a class which must be able to hold a type of float, double, long excetera. I would like to overload it in such a way that it can add two instances holding different types.

```
template <typename T>
class F{
public:
       F(const T & t){a=t;}
       T a;
       F & operator+= (const F & rhs);
}

template<typename T>
F<T> F::operator+= (const F & rhs){
       a+=rhs.a;
       return *this
```

This is just pseudo code I've kept out irrelevant bits where I'm actually trying to use this sort of solution.

Now when trying to use:

```
  F<int> first(5);
  F<int> second(4);
  first+=second; // Works

  F<int> third(5);
  F<float> fourth(6.2);
  fourth+=third; // wont work
```

I can see why this doesn't work as it assumes the rhs argument is the same type as the lhs. I can also see there are potential problems in performing an operation which is int += long as if the long is big the type would need changing.
What I can't seem to find is a nice way to solve the problem. I would appreciate your inputs. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make `operator+=` a template as well:

```
template <typename T>
class F{
public:
       F(const T & t){ a = t; }
       T a;

       template<typename T2>
       F& operator+=(const F<T2>& rhs);
}; // semicolon was missing

template<typename T>
template<typename T2>
F<T>& F<T>::operator+=(const F<T2>& rhs) {
       a += rhs.a;
       return *this; // semicolon was missing
} // brace was missing
```

Then you can do

```
F<int> a(4);
F<float> b(28.4);

b += a;

cout << b.a << endl; // prints 32.4
```

[Here is a working example](http://ideone.com/1BjKi).

Comment: Thanks Seth, I had tried mokas answer first then your edit in my code but it wouldn't compile. Thanks to your answer I believe I know the reason now. Because my code is quite large I had divided it into header and implementation using the cheat of declaring the templates I would use in the implementation file, ie template class F<float>; and template class F<int>; but forgot to provide one for the function.
Now I'm struggling to make one, I think it should be something like this:
template Variable<double> Variable<double>::operator+=(const Variable<float> & other);
but that doesn't work.

Comment: @wookie1, I think you're missing a `&` in your comment. `template Variable<double>& Variable<double>::operator+=(const Variable<float> & other);`

Comment: Ah, silly me I was trying all kinds of combinations trying to get that working, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
    template <typename T>
    class F{
    public:
           F(const T & t){a=t;}
           T a;
           template<typename T2>
           F & operator+= (const F<T2> & rhs);
    };

    template<typename T>
    template<typename T2>
    F<T>& F<T>::operator+= (const F<T2> & rhs){
           a+=(T)rhs.a;
           return *this
    }
```

EDIT:

fixed error, see comments

Comment: This is the right idea, but it won't compile; see @Seth's answer.

Comment: you mean due to the template<typename T, typename T2> part?

Answer (score 0):

You can templatize `operator+=`:

```
template<typename G> F<T> & operator+= (const F<G> & rhs);
```

...assuming you can somehow convert a `G` to a `T`.